# screen and workspace layout

Tags: interface

I have watched many Blender tutorials for various operations in Blender and they all seem to have lots of vertical tabs open that are customized for whatever they do most - see attached - but I can't find a tutorial on setting up these tabs or - for instance - where I can find the tissue dialog

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2):

The *Tissue Tools* are from the *Tissue* add-on. You can activate it in your preferences by ticking the checkbox (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*).

[image: Preferences]

The sidebar can be toggled by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>, through *View > Sidebar* or by clicking on the little arrow icon.

[image: View menu]

[image]

Comment: Yes - I activated it (in fact reinstalled it since the previous version was out of date) but I still can't find it anywhere - where does it show up - I've literally been through ervery drop down menu that I can find lol

Comment: And thanks for your response btw - looking further - and at some yet other videos, I just don't seem to have any of the toolbox panels that are shown on any of those - am I missing something? I haven't felt this dumb since Fusion 360 haha!         
 Thanks

Comment: @RobTee Sounds like you broke something when trying to install a different version of the add-on. Is it listed in the preferences? When you enable it, are there any error messages *Window > Toggles System Console*? Hard to say why you're missing tools without knowing what specific tool you're referring to. If it's not visible by default, then it's likely an add-on or a tool that is only visible in specific modes.

Comment: Thanks, nah I even installed a new version of Blender because the Tissue add-on was prompting me to do that - so everything is up to date except Bobby's brain heh.

Comment: sorry to keep adding on (no pun intended!) but I just watched another video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zo2phSY4hrE) and he said "yeah you just activate the add-on and it appears over here (showing a vertical tab now showing on the side of his main window) but mine is not doing that. So I think something is fundamentally wrong with the way I have my layout setup. Would the be a MAC thing? Forgot to mention that :P

Comment: OM (freaking) G!!! I found it - All I had to do was take the tiny, almost invisible < arrow on the upper right of my window - next to the world view stick and ball view controller thingy, and drag it out to the left - there it is!! Ok now for the bad news - whoever is writing and contributing to Blender needs to read **"The Humane Interface"** < - like soon! Really! Thanks for whoever I annoyed with this but glad I had somewhere to post. Oh - BTW - LOVE Blender - HATE Blender - need to learn more Blender

Comment: @RobTee This may sound stupid, but are you sure you have the sidebar displayed? Shortcut is **N**. Or go to *View > Sidebar*.

Comment: **Yes!** That would have done it. I had no idea that the sidebar N was an option - even though I have watched some real noob-specific videos. Maybe I'll have to make my own for the noob of the noob of the noob hehe. Thanks Jachym!